Programmatically access the overall average RGB color from the material icon?
Is there a way to programmatically access the overall average RGB color from the material icon?


Why do you need this? Could you provide some context?

Hi, sure, here's the background story: https://community.osarch.org/discussion/2106/drive-the-viewport-display-color

You should edit the question and provide the whole story summarized there. Unless you want to bet on people going to read a whole forum thread in order to help you. I mean, your choice of course. I am certainly not going to.
